# sendFile method asking for absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern

The `sendFile()` method is not checking for file in public folder, it is still trying to find the file in C drive, even though I have set the static path.

How do I know that only `sendFile()` is not checking for file in public folder? Because index.ejs file which is acting as homepage is using style.css from public folder, and it is working fine. When I search "localhost:5000/about.html", it is also working but "localhost:5000/about" is not working.

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("index", {name: "Aniket"});
});

app.get("/about", (req, res)=>{
    // res.sendFile(path.join(path.resolve(),"public","about.html"));
    res.sendFile("about.html");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("The server is working!");
});
```

The directory:(The above code is written in index.js)

```
>node_modules
>public
  |-> about.html
  |-> style.css
>views
  |-> index.ejs
 index.js
 package-lock.json
 package.json
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:441:11)
    at file:///c:/Users/kumar/OneDrive/Desktop/Web%20Development/Practice/index.js:21:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at SendStream.error (c:\Users\kumar\OneDrive\Desktop\Web Development\Practice\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
```

Edit: I understand that this might not be the best approach for using sendFile. I was used to working with PHP and MySQL and recently shifted to the MERN stack. While following a basic tutorial, I ran into this error.

Comment: The argument to `sendFile` is a pathname, not a URL. If it's not absolute (doesn't begin with `/`), it's interpreted relative to the server's working directory, NOT the caller's URL or the web root.

Comment: if the html file is in the same directory as your server file change code to `res.sendFile(./about.html)`

Comment: Specifically, https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile has all the details here, including examples. That said, don't use `sendFile` for an html page. You're already using `res.render` for your index, _do the same for `about`_. It doesn't matter whether it's a template or not: if it's a standalone HTML page already, then render will simply not replace anything in it. Or even better: if it's a standalone file, put it in your static dir and let `express.static` deal with it, no need for route. But don't use `sendFile` unless you're sending _actual_ files, as binary data.

Comment: I have added the directory in question, I have already added `express.static`, only `sendFile` is not able to use content directly from static dir, as you can see index.ejs file is able to use style.css which is also in static location directly, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`, I have not written absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Your `express.static` setup is wrong. `path.resolve` is a function, and needs some parameters to work. You have `path.resolve()` without any path. Try to change the line

`app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), "public")));` to

`app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve("./public"))));`

Comment: That didn't work either, even I thought that might the cause that's why I checked the path using `console.log` and I was getting correct path.

Comment: Try to run your app outside from OneDrive folder

Comment: It's my mistake, I should have explained what and all I have already tried, and I have already tried moving the files to other locations.

Comment: Your Node version is?

Comment: Node:v18.17.0 , ejs: v3.1.9 , Express: v4.18.2

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the response from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I attempted to explore alternatives. As he suggested, the approach of using the `sendFile` method for redirecting to a new webpage is not recommended. I found that the code functioned correctly when I utilized the `redirect` method instead.

Despite attempting various solutions, I encountered challenges in making the `sendFile` method redirect to files located in the static directory without utilizing an absolute path. However, since my primary goal was to navigate the user to a different webpage, this method still works fine.

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(), "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("index", {name: "Aniket"});
});

app.get("/about", (req, res)=>{
    res.redirect("about.html");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("The server is working!");
});
```

This result also indicates that there's no issue with the `express.static` method, as the path is reachable using the `redirect` method. The problem lies with the `sendFile` method. I would have thought that the developers had restricted the use to only absolute paths with the root address, making it the exclusive method, or perhaps they had even eliminated support for `express.static`. However, I've observed the same tutorial code functioning correctly with the exact same versions of Node.js, Express, and EJS. I'm beginning to suspect that this error is specific to my system.